# How to flip character when moving left unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to flip my character sprite when moving left in my game, and I have followed multiple tutorials however my sprite does not seem to flip. It is always facing the same way.

Below is my code for my character's movement. I have created a Flip() function and 2 if statements used to call the function. The character can move left, right, up and down (no jumping).

I cannot seem to see where an error would be and why it is not flipping, so any help would be appreciated. thank you.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    private Animator animate;
    public float moveSpeed = 6f;
    bool facingRight = true;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    Vector2 movement;

    private void Start()
    {
        animate = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        animate.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(movement.x));

        if(movement.x < 0 && facingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (movement.x > 0 && !facingRight)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        
       
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        Vector3 currentScale = gameObject.transform.localScale;
        currentScale.x *= -1;
        gameObject.transform.localScale = currentScale;

        facingRight = !facingRight;
    }
}
```

Updated code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    private Animator animate;
    public float moveSpeed = 6f;
    bool facingRight = true;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    Vector2 movement;

    private void Start()
    {
        animate = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        animate.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(movement.x));


        if (movement.x < 0 && facingRight)
        {
            
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;

        }
        else if (movement.x > 0 && !facingRight)
        {
            
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;

        }



    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        

    }

    void Flip()
    {
        Vector3 currentScale = gameObject.transform.localScale;
        currentScale.x *= -1;
        gameObject.transform.localScale = currentScale;

        facingRight = !facingRight;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the flipX property of the SpriteRenderer.

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
```

You have an animator attached to the game object, if the scale value is controlled by the animation clip, you cannot change it. A typical workaround is give the game object an empty parent and change its scale.

```
Player    <---- Change scale here
    Model <---- Animator here
```

Comment: I put the `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;` in my if and else if statement, and now my sprite flips when I press the left arrow, however when I press the right arrow it does not flip back.

Comment: `.flipX = false;` to flip back.

Comment: Hello, I changed it to `.flipX = false;` in the else if statement, however it still does not flip back.

Comment: Could you show your recent code?

Comment: I have added the updated code.

Comment: You need remove `facingRight`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. my sprite now flips both ways :)

Comment: I have a "chain" under one parent: two objects under one parent..a rat which has a head and tail/behind. So, I flip the Scale of both X and Z, keeping Y == 1, for the parent, and this works.

Answer (score 0):

transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f); you have to change y while fliping

will work better instead of using currentScale.x *= -1;
gameObject.transform.localScale = currentScale;

This code worked for me

```
private void Flip()
{
    // Rotate the player
    if (transform.localEulerAngles.y != 180 && !facingRight)
        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
    else if(transform.localEulerAngles.y != 0 && facingRight)
            transform.Rotate(0f, -180f, 0f);

    // player flip point of attck also flip is direction
    //transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: I replaced the Flip() function from my original code with this, however the sprite does not flip.

Comment: Try it removing first condition from if and else

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
        isLookingRight = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
        isLookingRight = true;
    }
```

[Going to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEZlW.png)

[Going to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S23P.png)